# How to unscrew this screw

Tags: screws, dishwasher

I want to take out my dish washer but there is a screw that I don't know how to unscrew.

I can't get the screwdriver straight on the screw head, only at an angle.

Any advise would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: use needlenose pliers to grip the screw and turn it ... you can also use a short screwdriver bit and pliers ... http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/151535522693-0-1/s-l1000.jpg

Comment: When you do get it out.  Consider filling the original stripped holes with a wood plug and drilling a pilot hole, so you can reinstall using the outer most hole.  You could also consider raising the dishwasher's legs at bit, so it fits tight up against the countertop.

Comment: Are there adjustable feet on the bottom of the dishwasher? You might be able to drop it just enough to get the clearance you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plastic should be flexible enough to bend a little.

Put the end of the screwdriver in the head of the screw and then try to force the screwdriver in or more strait while turning it. Apply pressure up into the screw as you turn it as well.

Somebody got it in, you should be able to get it out.

If you can not get it out or the head strips you could cut the screw with a mini hacksaw.

[image] [image]

Comment: I forced the screwdriver in and did it! Even though I scratched the shell it doesn't matter, because I'm replacing the dishwasher. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Empty the dishwasher and push that corner upwards and backwards. That should fold the tab back flat (like the left one) and give you the extra space you need.

Comment: The purpose of the tabs is to keep the dishwasher from moving. **It is not possible to push the dishwasher back when the tabs are secured with screws. In fact that is the whole reason for the question in the first place, to be able to move/remove the dishwasher**. The original screw placement hole was stripped out, that is why they used the back hole.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I know exactly what they're for. I also know that they will bend with sufficient force (happened when my kid fell on the open door). The one in the question is clearly bent differently from the other side and can probably be unbent. Hence my suggestion. I am fairly certain it wasn't the way it is now when the screw was put in.

Answer (score 1):

Grab it with a pair of pliers or vice grips and turn it counterclockwise.